# How to assign Json object a value with keys in a vector

Tags: c++, json, vector

I want to create a jsoncpp object, whose keys is stored in a std::vector, I want to have a way to create it. Please kindly check below sample. Thanks!

```
std::vector<std::string> keys = {"a", "b", "c"};
item["a"]["b"]["c"] = 1;

std::vector<std::string> keys = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
item["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"] = 1;
```

How to construct item object with keys in vector. Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of item[][][] in your sample?.

Comment: you can think item will become as below json object {
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": 1
        }
    }
}

Comment: You want item to be a 3d associative array?  Please be more specific about the problem that you are trying to solve.  Tell us a story about the problem so that it is easier to understand your goals.

Comment: As I said, currently, I know the json key names, it is in a vector, the first one is the root node, then the child node... which looks like  { "a": { "b": { "c": 1 } } } and I know the value is 1, I want to create a json object which has the related key and value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can begin building your JSON from the end of the array to the top:

```
std::vector<std::string> keys;
keys.push_back("a");
keys.push_back("b");
keys.push_back("c");
keys.push_back("d");

Json::Value json(Json::objectValue);
json[keys.back()] = 1;

for (int i = keys.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Json::Value tmp(Json::objectValue);
    tmp[keys[i]] = json;
    json = tmp;
}

Json::StyledWriter writer;
std::string text = writer.write(json);
```

Comment: Thanks Sga, I am used like this,:) I just want to know whether there any more graceful way.

Comment: Well, that seems the only way given JsonCPP API